# Wrapp elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, wrapper

I have some

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

I need to get all elements with checkbox and wrapp them different that final html get like this

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><i></i></label>
```

Is that possible only with Jquery?

Comment: You need to get outerHTML of checkbox parent?

Comment: You can use... drumroll please... [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: Txanks for .wrap(), but that doe not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
$('input:checkbox').wrap('<label class="checkbox" />').after('<i />')
```

```css
label.checkbox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label.checkbox i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: `.parent().append()` could be replaced with `.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

**CSS**

```
$(':checkbox').wrapInner('<i></i>').wrapInner('<label class="checkbox"></label>')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzmw9fop/)